# ColorAnimation affects two different objects with the same type WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two completely different sets of control objects with the same type, with ColorAnimation for both of them defined in the ControlTemplate. What's weird is somehow when the trigger for ColorAnimation activates in one of them, it also somehow activates in every object with the same type. It only happens in ColorAnimation, I've tried DoubleAnimation for example and it works as expected.

Here's the source code:

ToggleButton's style

```
 <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverBrush" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainHoverColor}, Path=Color}"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBackground" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource TogglerBackground}, Path=Color}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Border 
                        x:Name="PART_Border"
                        Background="{StaticResource BorderBackground}"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                        Tag="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                        CornerRadius="10">
                        <Button 
                            x:Name="PART_Toggler" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Margin="3 0 0 0">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Ellipse Fill="White"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Checked">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation 
                                        Duration="0:0:0.200" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Toggler" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                        To="32,0,0,0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation
                                            Duration="0:0:0.200" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Border" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="Red"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Unchecked">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation 
                                        Duration="0:0:0.200" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Toggler" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                        To="3,0,0,0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation
                                            Duration="0:0:0.200" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Border" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="Black"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Here's how the problem occurs:
[Screenshot GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLAE1.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical mistake but you unintentionally change the instance of `BorderBackground` itself. Change Border style like this.

```xml
<Border
    x:Name="PART_Border"
    Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
    Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
    Tag="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
    CornerRadius="10">
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource TogglerBackground}, Path=Color}"/>
    </Border.Background>
    ...
</Border>
```

Comment: Thanks this does work. So in this case we duplicate the instance of the SolidColorBrush? If it's a margin or text for example that references a StaticResource, we don't need to duplicate?